# C# equivalent of Qt's SimpleCrypt

Tags: c#, qt, security, encryption

What is equivalent of QT's [Simple encryption with SimpleCrypt](https://wiki.qt.io/Simple_encryption_with_SimpleCrypt) encryption and decryption in C#? I want to decrypt file which is encrypt in C++ using SimpleCrypt method.

Comment: It looks like Sha1 : QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Sha1);  Sha1 has a 20 byte key like the code.

Comment: "The SimpleCrypt class takes a 64 bits key in the form of a `quint64` ..." - You should probably avoid SimpleCrypt. Instead, use a library that provides high level primitives, like Seal and Unseal; Box and Unbox; etc. Here's an example from [Bernstein's `libsodium`](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/public-key_cryptography/sealed_boxes.html); here's an example from [OpenSSL EVP interfaces](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Asymmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption_of_an_Envelope); here's an example from [Lloyd's Botan](https://botan.randombit.net/manual/cryptobox.html).

Comment: Decrypt: `byteArray[pos] = (byte)(byteArray[pos] ^ lastChar ^ this.keyParts[pos % 8]);`, uh, XOR ciphers are not secure, please replace code instead.

Comment: I'm not going to allow to reopen this question, I guess people have to search for the solution themselves; Google is generally pretty good at finding GitHub resources...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleCrypt is not a standard encryption algorithm. You are better using any other well known encryption algorithm (such as [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard)). This way it will be easier for you to find implementations in any language you want, and you will get stronger encryption.

If you don't have control on the algorithm being used in the C++ program, You'll have to write your own SimpleCrypt implementation. You can start by reading the algorithm details [here](https://wiki.qt.io/SimpleCrypt_algorithm_details), then try reading [the C++ code](https://wiki.qt.io/Simple_encryption_with_SimpleCrypt#The_code) and write that in C#.

Comment: Wow, a recommendation to use RC4!

Comment: @zaph, Sorry, I haven't updated my cryptography knowledge in the last few years. Thanks for pointing out.